# Finding main active program on the screen

Tags: .desktop

Is it possible to see from the terminal which program has been in the past the main active window on the screen?

Comment: No. The window may no longer exist, the program may have stopped. Back when windowing systems were designed, it was deemed unnecessary, unacceptable overhead to do any sort of "accounting" on a per window basis, so there's no saved information, either.

Comment: Fair enough, but is there maybe any application that can be installed to keep track of it?

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site.  Questions asked (and possibly answered) in Comments are not indexed, and are of no use to other users.

Comment: Then why are there comments? There are plenty highly upvoted comments. You may also answer the question instead of commenting if you know the answer.